# RPi 3 B+ will not connect to hidden Wifi

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-3b+, wpa-supplicant

I have two devices, both are B+, one is a rev. 1.2 the other rev 1.3. I have configured one SD card and when used in the rev 1.2 it connects without issue to the hidden wifi network. However, when used in the rev 1.3, it will not connect. If I un-hide the network, the rev 1.3 connects as it should. I have tried un-hiding and then re-hiding the network but after a reboot, it will not connect. The wpa_supplicant.conf file is as below. This must be a hardware / firmware issue?? Any thoughts? The OS version is Linux raspberrypi 4.14.34-v7+. FYI - the network is secured using WPA/WPA2.

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
        ssid="<ssid name>"
        scan_ssid=1
        psk="<ssid_password>"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Comment: as far as I can tell, 3b+ are rev 1.3 ... rev1.2 are 3b (no +) - that may be the issue ... the hardware in the 3b+ is different to the 3b?

Comment: what's the output of `sudo rfkill list all`

Comment: Why is the SSID hidden? What do you think that buys you? Clue: it does **not** improve security in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had the time to look at the reason for this, but can confirm this problem at the time of writing.  A quick fix, for me at least is to run this command at the command line:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning essid <hidden_ssid> |grep <hidden_ssid>
```

It should show your hidden network ssid.  Omit the grep command to see the output of the entire scan.

This temporarily associates the hidden_ssid with the relevant network.
Your entry in wpa_supplicant.conf will then be picked up by the gui interface.

After doing this, and making sure your wired ethernet is down

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```

you may be able to associate on reboot without issuing the scanning command again.

My entry for the hidden network in my wpa_supplicant.conf looks like this:

```
network={
    ssid="hidden"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk="PASSWORD"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify they are both Pi 3B+ models.  The Ethernet, Wi-Fi and BT  chipset was updated for the 3B+.  See below [1](https://www.datenreise.de/en/raspberry-pi-3b-and-3b-in-comparison/) for details.

I have run into a few issues between the 3B and 3B+ on the Wi-Fi side.

Comment: Can you talk about what issues you have run into?